# Why did Valentine implant safety chips into his guards at his secret base?

Tags: plot-explanation, kingsman-the-secret-service

As it was explained in the movie, the chips that Valentine implanted into government members/royalty/famous people/his associates have 2 functions:

1. They provide protection from Valentine's SIM-cards and their
   "anger-waves";
2. They allow Valentine to dispose of the people who are going to
   spoil his plans (like Professor Arnold who was about to spill the
   beans);

The final act of *Kingsman: The Secret Service* (2014) takes place in Valentine's secret mountain base. This base is supposed to be distant enough from mobile coverage so Valentine's SIM-cards don't work there, which is proved by two things:

1. The scene where Eggsy knocks down Swedish minister to steal his laptop. Eggsy tells minister that he can't get a signal, and the minister pretty much confirms that only Valentine's private network can be used at the base;
2. Since neither Valentine, nor Gazelle, nor Eggsy, nor Merlin had these chips implanted and anger-waves had no effect on them, it's pretty safe to assume that there are no active SIM-cards of Valentine's at his secret base.

Why, then, did he implant all of his foot soldiers (and other staff members, apparently) with these chips, allowing Merlin to wipe them out with a single hack?

Comment: That location is pretty much a bunker for the event.  Is there any indication that even members of his security detail never left the base, ever? It would be pretty short-sighted to assume they'd never have to venture off-base and would not need protection, IMO, or to assume none could possibly be disloyal and in need of a personally targeted head-explosion (delivered via wi-fi signal).

Comment: For the same reason he implanted them into the others, he didn't fully trust them. He only trusted Gazelle.

Comment: Be it as it may, this is a rather major misstep for Valentine. The one that could easily be avoided had he removed/blocked away the head explosion function after the start of "V-day".